# why Word.Application.Selection.Find.Execute does not work in footnote and endnote

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, replaceall, footnotes

why Word.Application.Selection.Find.Execute does not work in footnote and endnote?
my code is:

```
object wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
object wdReplaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
object text = findWhat;
object replaceText = replaceWith;
object missing = Type.Missing;
object bFormat = true;
object forward = true;
Common.WordApplication.Selection.Find.Execute(ref text, ref missing, ref     missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref forward,
ref wrap, ref bFormat, ref replaceText, ref wdReplaceAll,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: i can replace a text in body of page but i cant do that operation in the footnote and end note section in microsoft word.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate between ActiveDocument.StoryRanges to get all story types in the document.
something like:

```
word.Range myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges[wdMainTextStory]
word.Range myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges[wdFootnotesStory]
myRange.Find.Execute(your parameters)
```

And so on.
Sorry I'm not fan with c#.